# DataGrid Cell Value

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagrid in my Project,one of it items name "UserID"

are they any way to make this column(Items) have a display membre and value membre like combobox ? to show user as username and save it as userID ?

Comment: You want to have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Since on your behalf of not posting any code or anything you have tried, here's a good start on what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i don't wont use combobox column, normal datagrid cell, are they any way to give this cell value and display membre in the same time ?

Comment: Not if it's not a DataGridViewComboBox ....

Comment: Only other way it create some variables and such, but that would be a mess to handle.